# How to bound the spectral norm of this kind of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-norm

I have asked the same question before but the contents were not complete, and I propose it again.

Assume that A, B are both symmetrical positive definite matrices, and
$$ 0 \prec aI  \preceq A \preceq bI $$
$$ A \preceq B \preceq (1+ \epsilon) A, \epsilon > 0$$
$$\gamma \in [0,1].$$

The background of this question is that $B$ is a matrix approximation of $A$ (Hessian of a strongly convex and smooth function) and the approximation error can be measured as the above.

Now we want an upper bound of $\Vert I - \gamma A B^{-1}\Vert_2 $ which can be seen as another measure of the approximation error.

Intuitively, since $B \succeq A$, this norm should be less than 1(I am not sure about this). And also, when $\gamma =0$, the corresponding norm should be $1$.

The main difficulty is that $A B^{-1}$ is not symmetrical, and thus we can not derive it in the following sense:
$$
\dfrac{1}{1 + \epsilon}A^{-1} \preceq B^{-1} \preceq A^{-1}\\
\dfrac{1}{1 + \epsilon}I  \preceq AB^{-1} \preceq I.
$$
Any help will be appreciated.

We have the following current results:
$$ I - \gamma A B^{-1} = (1 - \gamma)I + \gamma (B- A)B^{-1}, $$

and thus all the eigenvalues of $I - \gamma A B^{-1}$ are non-negative and even positive when $\gamma < 1$. And also the maximum eigenvalue of $I - \gamma A B^{-1}$ can be bounded:
$$\lambda_{max}(I - \gamma A B^{-1}) \leq 1 - \gamma \lambda_{min}(A B^{-1}) \leq 1- \gamma \dfrac{a}{b(1 + \epsilon)}.$$
But the spectral norm is the maximum singular value instead of the maximum eigenvalue.

Comment: You do have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|I-\gamma AB^{-1}\|
&=\|(1-\gamma)I+\gamma A(A^{-1}-B^{-1})\|\\
&\le(1-\gamma)+\gamma\|A\|\|A^{-1}-B^{-1}\|\\
&\le(1-\gamma)+\gamma\|A\|\frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}\|A^{-1}\|\\
&=(1-\gamma)+\frac{\gamma\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}\kappa(A)\\
&\le(1-\gamma)+\frac{\gamma\epsilon b}{(1+\epsilon)a}.\\
\end{aligned}
$$